# View Pager and Gridview wrap_content

Tags: java, android

У меня есть свой виджет который наследуется от LinearLayout. На этом layout находится view pager, а в нем GridView. Проблема в том, что когда я создаю диалог(и не только диалог), то у меня этот самый виджет занимает гораздо больше места чем нужно. Я пробовал wrap_content где только мог, но не помогло. Помогало только явное задание высоты layout, но это не тот способ который нужно. Пример лишнего места ниже на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка самого элемента в viewPager

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_dark_background" />

</LinearLayout>


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Вот сам класс которым я показываю диалог

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends LinearLayout {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPair<Integer, Integer>>> selected_interval_list = new ArrayList<>();
CustomDatePicker(Context c, AttributeSet a) {
    super(c, a);
    context = c;
   // setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    if (changed) {
        System.out.print(getChildCount());
        addView(get_DatePicker(2017));

    }
}

void set_selected_interval(ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPair<Integer, Integer>>> busy_list) {
    selected_interval_list.clear();
    selected_interval_list.addAll(busy_list);
    invalidate();
}

View get_DatePicker(int year) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int[] height = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_form, null);
        TextView mm = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.month);
        mm.setText(new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[i].toString() + " " + Integer.toString(year));
        final GridView gridview = (GridView) page.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        int pass = get_month_first_day_of_week(i, year);

        if (selected_interval_list.size() > i)
            gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(context, year, i, selected_interval_list.get(i), pass));
        else
            gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(context, year, i, new ArrayList<MyPair<Integer, Integer>>(), pass));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        page = (View) page;
        pages.add(page);
    }
    GridPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new GridPagerAdapter(pages, context);
    final ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    int p = viewPager.getMeasuredHeight();


    return viewPager;
}


void show_DatePickerDialog(int year) {

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5);
    linearLayout.addView(get_DatePicker(year));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}

private int get_month_first_day_of_week(int i, int year) {
    Calendar cc;
    cc = Calendar.getInstance();
    cc.set(year, i, 1);
    switch (cc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        case 1:
            return 6;

        case 2:
            return 0;

        case 3:
            return 1;

        case 4:
            return 2;

        case 5:
            return 3;

        case 6:
            return 4;

        case 7:
            return 5;

        default:
            return 0;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Разметку покажите

Comment: У вас диалог растянут во всю высоту экрана. Вы случайно в `WindowManager.LayoutParams` не поставили `height = ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT`?

Comment: @СергейГрушин добавил необходимый материал

Comment: @СергейГрушин не ставил